# Changes do not show up on google cloud compute engine VM

Tags: javascript, cloud, google-compute-engine

When I upload any changes in javascript files to my deployed site on Google cloud compute engine, the changes do not show up right away, if I load the js files in browser. The changes are physically there, validated by RDPing to the server. B

These changes sometime take 6 to 8 hours to show up in browser, and sometimes show up sporadically. What can I do to ensure that my changed js files take effect immediately on load?

I dont face this problem when I upload on my test server, which is not under cloud. Happens only on the google cloud server.

Comment: What are you using to serve your files? You might simply experience HTTP caching...

Answer (score 1):

Try opening your builtin browser debugger (for example right-click on your page, if using Chrome, and click "Inspect"). Now select the Network tab. Now reload. Now look at the sizes of the files. If they are very small, then probably the browser loaded cached copies. You can verify this by checking the "Disable cache" option in the Inspector.

If it works correctly and the file updates right away when you have the browser cache disabled, then you need to investigate with your web server software to see how to cause it to invalidate caches. One mechanism you can look into is called "ETags."

Answer (score 0):

What worked was  invalidating the cloud cache for the file. Lesson learnt: always add version numbers to your js files.